# How do i convert Array

Tags: java, dictionary, serialization, properties, hashmap

I am trying to serialize Observable Maps with an Serialiazation Proxy.
These two properties need to be saved.

```
 private final MapProperty<Integer, Cargo> allCargoStoredMap;
 private final MapProperty<Cargo, CargoLogisticData> cargoLogisticDataMap;
```

I thought i can save the values in an array like this:

```
this.cargoLogisticDataAsArray = warehouseManagement.getCargoCargoLogisticDataMap().values().toArray(new CargoLogisticData[0]);
this.cargoAsArray = warehouseManagement.getAllCargoStoredMapProperty().values().toArray(new Cargo[0]);
```

Then i want to pass i to an Constructor, and rebuild the properties.

```
    public Constructor (List<Cargor> cargos, List<CargoLogisticData>) {

    ObservableMap<Integer, Cargo> cargos = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
        
    //How do i add my cargos to a map?

    this.allCargoStoredMap = new SimpleMapProperty<>(cargos);
}
```

Any Idea how i can add the the List Entrys to my map?

I thought i maybe have to save 4 Arrays. Two with key, two with values. And then add those again.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a simple solution if I don't get it wrong

```
 allCargoStoredMap.values().stream().forEach(cargo -> {
     CargoLogisticData logisticsData=cargoLogisticDataMap.get(cargo);
     /*
     You have cargo and related logistics data here. 
     You can create which data model you want to store and use it
     */
 })
```